# How to sort structure C#

Tags: c#, sorting, structure

I've got this structure:

```
struct kluczyk
    {
        int id;
        char litera;
    }
```

Making a list:

```
List<kluczyk> posortuj = new List<kluczyk>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            kluczyk temp = new kluczyk(some char here, i);
            posortuj.Add(temp); 
        }
```

How to sort this list by litera?

Comment: What research have you done on how to sort a list, and what problems have you had implementing a solution based on the results of your research?

Comment: Maybe `posortuj.OrderBy(k => k.litera);` ?

Comment: [`List<T>.Sort(IComparer<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with an example at the bottom.

Comment: Of course posortuj.OrderBy(k => k.litera) works, I've lost at least an hour trying with different posortuj.Sort or Posortuj.OrderBy and I couldn't find an answer. Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are very simple LINQ methods to accomplish sorting by the property of an object. One is OrderBy:

```
var sortedEnumerable = unsortedEnumerable.OrderBy(a => a.property);
```

Likewise, you can use OrderByDescending to ascertain the reverse order of the above:

```
var sortedEnumerable = unsortedEnumerable.OrderByDescending(a => a.property);
```

Note that these return a new enumerable and do not sort in place.

If you needed more complex sorting logic, or if you wanted to sort the kluczyk object itself and not any given property, you'd want to create your own object that implements IComparer and establishes less-than/equal/greater relationships between your objects.

Brad Christie included a link to [`List(T).Sort (IComparer<T>`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which I've reproduced here unless he wants to make his own answer.

Comment: Your own answer is fine. I just figured I'd avoid the introduction of lambda and the `using System.Linq;` include.

Comment: @BradChristie Oh, yeah, I didn't necessarily think this was better. But comments get autodeleted, so if I see an answer with useful comments and no answers I like to at least point to the resources given by the commenters.